# How to setup local domain name servers for an institute LAN?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, local-area-network, bind

My institute offers students results, library services, and data server services on their LAN by providing the IP addresses of the machines holding the respective data. However as time passes these IP addresses change.

So I want to establish a mechanism where students could access these services through names instead of using their IP addresses directly. In the event that the IP changes for these machines, the name could be updated behind the scenes with the new address.

I tried to search for the solution over the Internet, and I found bind9.

Would that be the right solution? If not then what else? And if so then guide me through the process.

I think using bind9 would require me to make some changes not only on the server side, but also on the client side, am I right or wrong?

Comment: You will get some pointers about where to go, but this site is not an on-demend tutorial site. Once somebody suggests an architecture for you to use, you need to go off and work in implementing it yourself. Then if you have specific questions about the implementation or server specific software, you can come back and ask those here.

Answer (score 1):

The precise solution will depend on whether you use Windows or Linux based severs.  In either case, however you will probably want to set up
- a DNS server to map domain names to IP addresses
- a DHCP server to hand out IP addresses and details of the DNS server

You can then either get your clients to register their addresses with the DNS server or get the DHCP server register on their behalf.

If you provide more details on the servers you are running, a more detailed answer can be given

Comment: I am using ubuntu 10.10/fedora, and the major problem with approach is that I can't contact everyone in the network to make changes in their system to adapt to bind requirements, what I can do is make changes on these respective servers offering services.

Comment: It can't be done properly if all you can touch is those specific servers. DNS *has* to involve the clients in some way. If your clients get their IP from DHCP, modify the DHCP server to include the internal DNS, as suggested. If your clients all have static addresses, you either proactively email people and/or make the necessary changes on each (and I'd strongly suggest you convert clients to DHCP for the future), or else you wait for something to break, and make the changes then.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setting up a bind (or other DNS) server is the right solution. Then your important services will have static names no matter where in the IP namespace they get assigned. Your network will need to be adapted a little. The DHCP servers will need to give out your DNS server in the nameservers field, so that clients that connect will use your new server to resolve names to numbers. You should have at least two nameserver setup, a primary and a secondary.